# Why does Javascript not run from top to bottom like python does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm learning JS right now through Dr. Yu's bootcamp, but I do already have experience with C++ and python. I'm a little confused about why JS seems to run out of order, especially seen through working with MongoDB.

For example,

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Item.find().then(function (docs) {
    if (docs.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems)
        .then(function () {
          console.log("added");
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
    res.render("index", { pageTitle: "List", newListItems: docs });
  });
});
```

In this example, I would assume that if there are no documents in the db, we go to the insertMany function, then when that if-statement ends, we move out to the res.render where "docs" will be populated; however, it still renders 0 newListItems (the fix is to do a res.redirect("/"))

In another example, if I do something like add things to a DB then db.find() to console it, the console actually first shows the db.find() then gives me the success message for successful adding. Can anyone help explain why this is?

Comment: Promises are asynchronous operations.

Comment: You are just discovered asynchronous code execution and the event loop.